# CATPCA - rotation failed to converge, but still get a Rotated Component Loadings matrix

Tags: pca, spss, factor-analysis

I am conducting CATPCA using SPSS26 with six factors - after running it, I get a Rotated Component Loadings matrix; however, there is a footnote saying "Rotation failed to converge in 9 iterations". Reading previous posts and forums, it seems that I would need to increase the number of iterations - however, it is already set at 100, and increasing it to 200, etc, makes no difference.

When I look at the matrix, all the loadings and how the items converge across the 6 factors make (theoretical) sense, so I was wondering if I need to worry about the lack of convergence?

Comment: Practically, you should not worry much. Go ahead with these results. Some factor structures are hard to converge in a rotation, still, the rotation brings it close enough to the "simple structure" to be interpreted. Maybe you try also to reduce the number if extracted conponents.

Comment: I might recommend you also this _if_ you want real _factor_ analysis instead of PCA (CATPCA is still a PCA). Decide, in CATPCA, on the number of dimensions m. Save the produced quantified varibles in CATPCA. Use these as input in Factor analysis (with the extraction method not Principal Components but, say, Principal Axis) and extract m factors there. Rotate and interpret there. If needed, repeat the whole path with another m. Until you arrive at most interpretable loadings.